# transform csv into different format

Tags: arrays, bash, csv

Using BASH, I need to transform the csv output I receive from a data source into a different format to make it easier to import into SQL server.

The source format is a single row with one data point then a comma then any number of hosts separated by a colon.

The target format is a data point then a comma then one of the hosts on a line. Then the next line would be the same data point then a comma then the next host.

Basically I need to change from 1 row per data point and numerous colon separated hosts to multiple rows per data point, with only one of the hosts per row

Source format:

```
data1,host1:host2
data2,host4:host5:host6
data3,host4:host7:host1:host5:host9
```

I need

```
data1,host1
data1,host2
data2,host4
date2,host5
data2,host6
data3,host4
data3,host7
data3,host1
data3,host5
data3,host9
```

Comment: Thank you for reformatting my question fedorqui.

Comment: no problem :) You can edit it yourself using the "edit" button and the tools the editor offers.

Answer (score 1):

Since the format is like

```
field1,subfield1:subfield2:...
```

and has to become

```
field1,subfield1
field1,subfield2
field1,...
```

I would use...

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
     {n=split($2,a,":")
      for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print $1, a[i]}' file
```

This sets the field separator to the comma. Then, it explodes the second field on colons. Since `split` returns the number of pieces, then it is a matter of looping through the extracted values.

#### Test

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {n=split($2,a,":"); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print $1, a[i]}' a
data1,host1
data1,host2
data2,host4
data2,host5
data2,host6
data3,host4
data3,host7
data3,host1
data3,host5
data3,host9
```

Comment: It looks like I screwed up  my own question. To use a more specific set of data.  there are 3 columns of data, not just 2.
hardware1,data1,host1:host2:host3
hardware1,data2,host3:host4:host7
hardware1,data3,host9:host3:host1
hardware2,data4,host1:host3:host5
hardware2,data5,host8:host2:host1

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 ways:

```
awk -F'[,:]' '{for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1","$i}' source.file

perl -F'[,:]' -lane '$d=shift @F; print "$d,$_" for @F' source.file

while IFS=",:" read -ra fields; do
     for ((i=1; i<"${#fields[@]}"; i++)); do
         echo "${fields[0]},${fields[i]}"
     done
done < source.file
```

Comment: thank you.  Not sure if you saw but I screwed up my own question.  I actually have 3 columns, not 2.  see the comment in the above answer where I explain them

Comment: @CES You have to do by yourself even a minimum. `awk ... i=3; i<=NF; i++) print $2 ...`

Comment: @CES, if you want to change your requirements, edit the question. Don't leave clues scattered around in comments. I think fedorqui and I have given you enough to go on. If you have specific questions about the code I've given you, then come back and leave a comment about it.

Comment: yes sorry, new here.  Both of you have provided excellent information.  I tried to bump the score but it won't let me.  what has been provided fixed my issue.  I am greatly appreciative.